# Debian Jessie (8.7) LXDE how to type multiple languages

Tags: debian, keyboard, lxde, language

**Background information:** *Debian Jessie (8.7) LXDE Desktop Environment. `ttf-unfonts-core` and `fonts-unfonts-extra` packages installed (so I can view Korean characters).*

Right now I can view and type ***English (US)*** of course since I setup ***Debian*** using ***English*** (time zone set to Korea of course). But, I also want to be able to type ***Korean*** (***English*** as main language, ***Korean*** secondary). I have tried using **"Keyboard Layout Handler"**, but unchecking **"Keep system layouts"** and adding ***Korean*** language does not work. To switch to ***Korean*** I tried moving **"KR"** up in the **"Keyboard Layouts"** section in **"Keyboard Layout Handler"**. And setting the keyboard shortcut toggle and using that. I still can't type ***Korean*** (only ***English***).

How do I type ***English and Korean*** (switch between them and set ***English*** as main language if possible)? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: https://10wontips.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/typing-in-korean-on-lubuntu-1310.html ? lubuntu is lxde. Ok based on Ubuntu so might be slightly differfent

Comment: @arochester LXDE on Debian is different from the one on Lubuntu (slightly). I don't have Language Support Settings in the bottom left menu/I can't find it in the menu (bottom left). I don't even have iBus installed. Trying to install `im-switch` tries to install `im-config`. I can install `imhangul-common`. I can't run `im-switch` in the terminal because I can't install it.

**TLDR;** Lubuntu is different from my Debian LXDE and so the instruction on the website you gave me does not match or work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install a keyboard switcher - Korean input (Hangul) requires a unique one that does not come with most desktop environments.

These instructions aren't tested, but should be the general approach for any Debian based distro:

1. Add Korean to your /etc/locale.gen

`sudo bash -c "echo ko_KR.UTF-8 UTF-8 >> /etc/locale.gen"`

2. Install ibus-hangul (a keyboard switcher)

`sudo apt install ibus-hangul`

3. Restart your computer
4. Run `ibus-setup`, and add 한국어 - Hangul to your Input Method
5. Run `ibus-daemon -d` in a terminal to start `ibus`
6. Hit Ctrl + Space to swap between languages

Your hotkey is configurable through the `ibus-setup`.

For anyone else reading this, I wrote several guides on Linuxreviews.org for Korean input, so if you have a different distro or desktop environment and want Korean input, check it out: https://linuxreviews.org/Category:Korean_Input_HOWTOs